# Threads in application server and connections in HttpServer

Tags: multithreading, application-server, httpserver

I'm building a system, I will use two servers and one load balancer, 
This company has more than 60,000 users and they expect 10,000 concurrent users, all transactions will occurs within 5 seconds

I'm not sure how about this for each server:

Amount of connections in HttpServer
Amount of threads in application server

I understand that I will find out this numbers when the system is in production but I need to start with something

any suggestion or advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is about Capacity Planning I can give some suggestions as below, however all depend on the technical feasibility  and business requirements of your system.

- Try to find out your maximum capacity which you need to support. So you can do required stress test to figure this out.
- Make sure system capable of improving performance by  horizontally with clustering etc.
- Decide on predicted capacity requirement(CR) , CR may be H/W ,bandwidth etc

Predicted CR =  Current CR + 30%*Current CR

- Finally this is about continuous improvements , keep eye on the changes .

  Check how reliable the system is , decide on changes to H/W , Software , Architecture etc.

[image]

Hope this add some value to you.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a test-server and extrapolate the numbers from there (get some time to do the research to come up with an educated guess).

For example, the "amount of threads in application server" depends on what kind of HTTP-server you use. Some servers can process hundreds of connections with a single thread, but badly programmed/configured servers might end up using 1 thread per connection.

The performance requirement "all transactions will occurs within 5 seconds" needs some further detailing. Showing web-pages with data (from a database) to a user may not take more than 3 seconds (if it takes longer, users get irritated), but ideally should be less than 1 second (an average user would expect that). On the other hand,  it might be OK to take 10 seconds to store data from a complex form (as long as the form is not used too often).

I would be skeptical about the load requirement "they expect 10,000 concurrent users". That would mean 1 in 6 company employees is actively using the web-application. I think this would be 'peak usage' and not 'average usage'. This is important to know with respect to the performance requirements and costs: if the system must adhere to the performance requirements during peak usage, you need more money for better and/or more hardware.